# Bivariate Normal

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, covariance

Let $X \sim \cal{N}(1, 3)$ and $Y \sim \cal{N}(2, 3)$ random variables. Suppose that $\operatorname{cov}(X, Y) = 1$. Consider
transformation of these random variables: $U = X + Y$ and $V = X − Y$.

---

I need to find the joint density function of $U$ and $V$.

How to tackle this problem. What can I get from $\operatorname{cov}(X, Y) = 1$? I've tried a few ways but ended up with nothing.

Comment: Find mean and covariance matrix of $(U,V)^T$ and apply [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Density_function).

Comment: Covariance between $X$ and $Y$ would give you correlation coefficient $\rho$. So if $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal, then you have all the five parameters of $(X,Y)$. Now you could just transform $(X,Y)\to(U,V)$ to get the joint density of $(U,V)$.

Comment: Similar post:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336285/bivariate-normal-distribution-finding-the-joint-distribution-of-functions-of-ra?rq=1.

Answer (score 0):

**This approach involves a reference to PCA.**

Say, $X$ & $Y$ are standardized and the correlation between them is $\rho$. In terms of correlation matrix, it can be written as $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \rho \\
    \rho & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

If you find the eigenvectors of this correlation matrix, you will see that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,-1)$ are the eigenvectors. Essentially, in these two directions, we can find the maximum and minimum variance - Reason behind why they are called Principal Components (PC).

Also, an important property of these PCs is that they are orthogonal to each other - an increase/decrease along one direction is not going to affect in the other direction.

Now, coming to your original problem, since $U$ and $V$ are along the directions of PCs, we can assume that they are independent. Therefore, you can simply multiply the marginal distributions to get the joint distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Covariance is bilinear and symmetric so that: $$\mathsf{Cov}(U,V)=\mathsf{Cov}(X+Y,X-Y)=\mathsf{Cov}(X,X)-\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)+\mathsf{Cov}(Y,X)-\mathsf{Cov}(Y,Y)=$$$$\mathsf{Var}(X)-\mathsf{Var}(Y)=3-3=0$$