# Joint distribution of functions of normal variables

Tags: statistics

I have a problem analogous to the one here: [Bivariate Normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2715724/bivariate-normal?noredirect=1&lq=1)

except I have $U = 2X + Y$ and $V = X - Y$, and $Corr(X, Y) = p$ some arbitrary $p$.

Some of the comments suggest that I should find particular matrix and then apply the density formula for multivariate normal distribution. The problem is that I cannot assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and thus I cannot assume that $U$ and $V$ are normal, so how am I allowed to use the density function for multivariate normal distribution?

Comment: You need the variances of $X$ and $Y$ (unless you know they are the same).  Then work on the variances and covariances remembering covariance is bilinear and symmetric

Comment: @Henry I have calculated the variances and covariances and gotten the mean vector and covariance matrix. I know that, given these vector and matrix, there exists a formula to calculate the density of bivariate normal distribution. The answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336285/bivariate-normal-distribution-finding-the-joint-distribution-of-functions-of-ra?rq=1 uses that approach. I don't understand why I'm *allowed* to use that formula though, since we don't know that $U$ and $V$ are normal.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are bivariate normal then $U$ and $V$ are too, due to the linear combination property of multivariate normal distributions.